# Deploying a .Net Application

Tags: .net

I do have certain queries while deploying a .net windows application

1. whether we need .Net framework to be installed in the deploying machine?
2. If not so, whether my application setup(.exe) includes compiler or class libraries
    integrated with the setup
3. As, well as can i deploy my .net application in any other platform other than
    windows, will it support the setup(.exe) format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> whether we need .Net framework to be installed in the deploying
>   machine?

Yes. If it is not installed, then the setup wizard or your program can install it, or, alternatively, you can prompt the user to install it.

> If not so, whether my application setup(.exe) includes compiler or
>   class libraries integrated with the setup

The .NET framework is required, whether you include your class libraries with your setup.

> As, well as can i deploy my .net application in any other platform
>   other than windows, will it support the setup(.exe) format.

You can deploy your application to Linux and Mac with minimal modification using [Mono](http://mono-project.com). You can also deploy your .NET application to mobile platforms with your current code base, though this will require more modifications.

Comment: Thanks for ur kind reply & answers and now im much clear about my understandings in deploying a windows application.

Comment: @Kamal. You are welcome. Please accept this answer by pressing the tick so that future users will be able to use it as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

1. yes, the .NET framework is required on the target machine
2. see 1.
3. if you plan to deploy your application on a (for example) linux box with mono, "it depends" on your application. If you use .NET 2 target level, it has a fairly good chance to run :)

Comment: As far as I know, yes. I've run many .NET applications (compiled with VS2005) on linux without any modifications, only copying the .exe files to the linux box and executing them with mono (without compiling them with mono)

Comment: @Kragen, that is correct for more simple projects. Any projects depending on native/unmanaged libraries or file system access will likely need to be modified a little bit. It would also be better to compile using Mono.

Comment: @Matten, For modifying a little bit in my application using mono will it be user friendly as VS2005 or accessing it will be tricky..